# Powershell line of code does not run when called through function but will run directly. What could be possible causes?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a powershell script with the following code in it...

```
$appdir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$xfrdir = $appdir + "\xfr\"
$cfgFile = "ofx_config.cfg"
$cfgPath = $appdir + "\" + $cfgFile
$configData = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
#  --- some other code here...
function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        $configData = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
    } 
}
#  ---some other code here
load-config
```

When I just RUN this script in the ps ISE, load-config runs because it is at the end of script (i verified this with a breakpoint) but the $configData variable remains empty.

But if I immediately copy and past the line `$configData = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"` into the powershell command line and run it then $configData is loaded with data.  Does anyone have any ideas what might be going on?

**EDIT**
I think that what you are saying is that $configData in `$configData = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"` is being treated as a whole separate variable (and is local to the function) because of scoping rules.  I thought it would be more like a c# class and so would assign to the script level variable of the same name.

I am LOVING powershell but dynamic typing does make things trickier.

**EDIT 2**
Both answers were insightful.  In such a case I usual give the answer to the person with the fewest reputation.  And I did in fact Andy's second example in any case.

Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping issue with variable `$configData`. When you set it's value in the function it is not available outside. You can use a scope modifier to fix it or return the value.

Check out `get-help about_scopes` or click [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315289.aspx).

Scope Modifier:

```
$cfgPath = 'C:\Test.xml'
$script:configData = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        $script:configData = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
    }
}
load-config
$configData
```

Note - Your ArrayList gets overwritten using `Import-Clixml` and is a different type on return.

Return the new value:

```
$cfgPath = 'C:\Test.xml'
function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        $data = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
        return $data
    }
}
$configData = load-config
```

Answer (score 4):

You create new variable with name `$configData`. You have several options (depending on your environment/script/...)

The most obvious is - just return the value and assign it to config data

```
function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
    } 
}
$configData = load-Config
```

You might also use object and its property like this:

```
$configData = @{Data = $null}
function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        $configData.Data = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
    } 
}
```

Or it is possible to use `script:` scope:

```
function Load-Config () 
{
    if (test-path ($cfgPath))
    {
        $script:configData = Import-Clixml -path "$cfgPath"
    } 
}
```